# Mailbox Redirect after disconnecting mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

On Exchange 2010 Management Console, If I Create a transport rule to redirect a user's email to their personal account, and disconnect the mailbox..... will there be any auto reply? Will the redirect still occur?

Answer (score 0):

transport rules are in other level than mailbox (you use address as string, not AD object) - it should still works. But you should test (esp. because we did not know about details on you rule)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the action used in the transport rule.

If you choose to redirect the message, it will be forwarded without NDR.

If instead you choose to copy or bcc the message, Exchange will also try to deliver the message to the original account, and so will report a delivery failure if that doesn't exist anymore (or it's disconnected).